# Python - closing a server socket while it's waiting for accept()

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, tkinter

I've been scouring for an hour to find an answer on this one -- got close, but not quite there.

The issue is that I'm using [this basic approach](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) to implement a socket server, but (of course) it hits the line with the `accept()` and freezes there.  What I want is to be able to have the user click a checkbox control in a Tkinter GUI and have the socket be listening, or closed, on demand.  A flag/semaphore to control the `while` loop doesn't help by itself; in concert with that, I also have to send a 'dummy' connection to get the server to iterate through the loop instead of just sitting at the `accept()` forever.  Which would work of course, but it just feels klunky.

After much effort I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983839/how-do-i-close-a-server-socket-while-it-is-waiting-for-a-connection) but the solution -- while it's a nice one -- still seems to still depend on the connection handler to raise the event that triggers the exit.  Which in turn means that I'd still need some kind of dummy connection to make it happen, instead of being able to interrupt/destroy/whatever the server socket while it's stopped at the `accept()`.

So is there any way to get around needing a connection before you can get the server socket closed?

Comment: Can you set the socket to nonblocking and use `select`? That way your accept call will never block. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets

Comment: It looks like that will work.  I'd used `select` before, but only for client-side apps where I wanted to have a timeout waiting for a host response.  It didn't occur to me that it could work just as well here.  Thanks!